# A word for words that are both the same and opposite

Tags: synonyms, antonyms, obscure-terms

I just had a conversation where the sentence 'The system is broken because it's fixed!' was correctly spoken under the pretense where fixed means that it's rigged. Assuming that context of rigged matches as a weak synonym for broken, the question came up - what's the word for a pair of words that are simultaneously synonyms and antonyms?

I am not asking about autoantonyms. I am not even looking for a single word. I am trying to find a term to describe the relationship of two different words, where one is an autoantonym and where one of its definitions is synonymous with the second word, causing the two words to be synonyms and antonyms at the same time.

In my example:

- fixed = rigged: *fixed* and *rigged* are synonyms
- fixed = repaired: *fixed* and *rigged* are antonyms

What is the label given to the relationship between *fixed* and *rigged*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a term for a word that serves as its own antonym?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171365/is-there-a-term-for-a-word-that-serves-as-its-own-antonym) See also [Can anyone provide me with a list of English words that are their own antonyms?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1820/can-anyone-provide-me-with-a-list-of-english-words-that-are-their-own-antonyms)

Comment: Well, you could say that they are "fantastic" or they're "incredible".

Comment: @Hot If I could upvote you for that, I would. Good ol' rookie rules.

Comment: @jakethedev I've edited your question to make the example explicit (feel free to roll back if it doesn't help). Yours is an interesting question, though I'm not sure whether there is a canonical answer. You're asking for the relationship between a word and a separate contronym. Perhaps you could say the two words are *contronymous*.

Comment: Another related recent thread: Words which can have the same or opposite meanings in different contexts http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/334695/term-for-words-which-can-have-the-same-or-opposite-meanings-in-different-context

Comment: Thanks @Lawrence, that does a much better job of expressing the idea!

Comment: @jakethedev I hope you're still thinking about this 5 years later! We just found your amazing example here after a conversation that went, "Is she sometimes sharp with you?" "No, she's just blunt"! Sharp and blunt are opposites that mean (almost) the same thing. We want more!

Answer (score 2):

You seem to describe an ***[auto-antonym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-antonym)***, "a word with a homograph (another word of the same spelling) which is also an antonym."

*Fixed* can be construed as an auto-antonym since it means both "working properly" and "not working properly—because rigged."

Any auto-antonym can be paired with one of its synonyms to create a pair of different words that are both synonyms and antonyms. For example, the pair *fixed*/*broken*. It seems doubtful that there is a special name for such pairs.

Here is the complete passage from Wikipedia which gives many alternative names for the phenomenon:

> An *auto-antonym* (sometimes spelled *autantonym*), or *contronym* (also spelled *contranym*), is a word with a homograph (another word of the same spelling) which is also an antonym (a word with the opposite meaning). An auto-antonym is alternatively called an *antagonym*, *Janus word* (after the Roman god), *enantiodrome*, *self-antonym*, *antilogy*, or *addad* (Arabic, singular *didd*). It is a word with multiple meanings, one of which is defined as the reverse of one of its other meanings. This phenomenon is called *enantiosemy*, *enantionymy* or *antilogy*.

Comment: Alright, I get the autoantonym part - I'm still left in curiosity of the way to describe two words that are antonyms and synonyms at the same time. I.e. the relationship of fixed and broken, or the relationship of any other autoantonym with a word that is synonymous with only one of its contradictory definitions.

Comment: Note that Janus was the god with two faces, looking in two directions at once. "January" is named after Janus because it looks back into the old year and forward into the new year.